# angularjs selector Assign values in Remote fetching with custom service Mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, multi-select

I am using angularjs-selector.js(https://github.com/ssotomayor/angular-selector) for multi-select functionality 
My case scenario applies with Remote fetching with custom service mode of this plugin 
reference url:-
http://plnkr.co/edit/YdzF58o9ykYvMwP5Udza?p=preview

```
angular
    .module('myApp', ['selector'])
    .service('$countries', ['$q','$http', function ($q, $http) {
        function Countries() {}
        Countries.prototype.search = function (search) {

          var def = $q.defer();
          if(search){

            var settings = {
                url: 'http://services.groupkt.com/country/search',
                method: 'GET',
                cache: true,
                params: {
                    text: search
                },
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    var countries = angular.fromJson(data).RestResponse.result;
                    return countries.map(function (country) {
                        return {
                            name: country.name,
                            code: country.alpha2_code
                        };
                    });
                }
            };
            return $http(settings);

        }
        else{
          def.resolve([])
        }

        return def.promise;
        };
        return new Countries();
    }])
    .controller('ExampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$countries', function ($scope, $countries) {

        $scope.countries = [ "BR" ];
        $scope.remote = function (search) {
            return $countries.search(search);
        };
    }]);
```

now everthing works as expected ,

in my scenario  i use grid with edit functionality with ngdialog box 
while editing i wanted to assign those values back to multiselect which is not happening

However, there is feature to add user inputs to multiselect , i was thinking one can reuse the functionality and can be effective applied for edit purpose.